# Aprilaire 700 humidifier not working properly

Tags: hvac, humidifier

The fan does not seem to be running.  How can I determine what the problem is?   I'm not sure if it's the fan, solenoid or the computer board.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You'll need to provide us with more information: when did this start? what are the symptoms? pictures?

Comment: Any error codes on display, red or yellow flashing lights?  Not running in auto or manual mode?

Answer (score 1):

humidifiers can be complex devices.  first step is check power at the board and make sure you haven't blown a board fuse or a fusible link.  assuming the board has power, check to see if the fan gets power when you turn on the power.  if no power to the fan, and all the wires are good, then chances are the power supply on the board is shot, or the control module is shot.  does it have momentary switches or good old fashioned "click" knobs or switches )ie SPST or DPST?

Comment: Is your shift key broken?  It is customary to use capitalization of words at the beginning of sentences.

Comment: e e cummings is keeping his name private.   ;-)

Comment: It's a good answer, though.